# Boost module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' Windows Qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I need to build my code using boost lib, my environment is

```
Windows 8, Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2013 64 Bit
```

When I build the code I getting the error like

```
libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_58.lib(thread.obj):-1: error: LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

My pro file looks

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_58_0/
LIBS += -LC:/local/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib/ -llibboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_58
```

I need to build the application for 64 bit architecture.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks 
Haris

Comment: Seems like you have 32bit version of your boost libs. Download or build them in 64bit

Comment: Ok I downloaded from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/ the exe boost_1_58_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe. Now I have the libs in the directory \boost_1_58_0\lib64-msvc-12.0. But still I am getting the error like   ` error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj`

Comment: Are you mixing debug and release libraries?

Comment: Probably,  If I consider thread I am having -llibboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_58 \
                                                -llibboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_58 \
                                                -llibboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-1_58 \
                                                -llibboost_thread-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58 \